# Setup Project Installer add registry entry only if debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, installation, conditional-statements, setup-project

I'm creating an installer for my application (Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010). I wish it to add some registry entries, but only if it's in debug mode. Can I achieve this?
There is a property `Condition` if you add a registry entry, but none of theese works:

```
    %DEBUG=1
    DEBUG=1
```

Please help,
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property to tell you the MSI is built by the Debug or Release build. From what you I know you also cannot have a registry value added just in one of the builds from the VS editor.

A solution would be to create a post-build event in VS that [inserts rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368568%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the [Registry table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the MSI build on debug.

To see what rows to insert in the table just build the MSI with the values in it, open it with Orca and see what it adds in the package. It should add entries in Registry, Component, and FeatureComponent tables. However, you could simply the scripts to have only entries in Registry table created by assigning the new values to an existent component from the package.